# FileInfo object gives exception

Tags: c#

We are using C# object for getting File Information.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileName) // this line throw an exception
```

That raises this exception:

> Not a valid Win32 FileTime. Parameter name: fileTime

We are trying to open word file and that word file has a creation date as `20 April 30086 12.40.16 PM`.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve it?

Comment: What does `FileName` look like? Also, why does the document have such a large creation date?

Comment: i just give example, i am passing filename in proper format, i mean there is no issue with passing filename in fileinfo object..FileName is simple like

Comment: FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\\1.doc")

Comment: See [similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08f5f26c-cf5d-442e-bb52-0a2dc4bad3d3/not-a-valid-win32-filetime-parameter-name-filetime?forum=msbuild). Check if the filename has a valid creation datetime and check if it happens on other environments too (might be a VS installation issue).

Comment: Have you tried calling `File.Exists(fileName)` first, just to see if there is nothing wrong with the path itself?

Comment: Obviously `20 April 30086 12.40.16 PM` is not a valid creation date. How did the file get a creation date many millennia in the future?

Comment: There is a issue because of that not valid creation date, but that files we received from client end so we can not say anything related to how that dates in file are there.

Answer (score 0):

The time stamp doesn't look very correct. 
Try one of those and see if FileInfo can read the file with new creation date:

```
(Get-Item .\asd.txt).creationTime=(Get-Date)
(Get-Item .\asd.txt).lastaccesstime=(Get-Date)
(Get-Item .\asd.txt).lastwritetime=(Get-Date)
```

For date time formatting see:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx

Got it from here:
https://superuser.com/questions/292630/how-can-i-change-the-timestamp-on-a-file